# Delete entry from SQL table with connections inside other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a question. I've this table structure here:

[image]

When I have now an issue in my table which has also different labels in my labels table and I want to delete the issue now, do I need to delete the labels before?

I'm planing to delete the entry this way:

```
DELETE FROM issues WHERE issue_id = 2;
```

The entries in my labels table are:

```
---------------------------------
| id | issue_id | label         |   
---------------------------------
| 1  | 2        | Apple         |
---------------------------------
| 1  | 2        | Orange        |
---------------------------------
| 1  | 2        | Banana        |
---------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You should delete entries which reference your issue_id before you can delete it in the base table itself.
First you'll have to delete it from the labels table, then you can delete it from the issues table.